# PostgreSQL getting row where one column is min

Tags: sql, postgresql

My second PostgreSQL-Question today... I'm sure the solution is simple, but I just don't know how to do it.

Table I work on:

```
CREATE TABLE separabilities 
  ( 
     data_bands      TEXT[] NOT NULL, 
     thematic_class1 TEXT NOT NULL, 
     thematic_class2 TEXT NOT NULL, 
     jm_dist         DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL 
  )
```

My Query:

```
select sep.data_bands,
       sum(sep.jm_dist)/count(sep.data_bands) as avarage_jm_dist, 
       min(jm_dist)
from separabilities as sep
group by sep.data_bands
order by avarage_jm_dist
```

What I get:
[image: result subset]

What I need:

Two more colums, containing the thematic classes corresponding to the minimal distance.

Like that:
data_bands -- avarage_jm_dist -- min -- thematic_class1 -- thematic_class2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY data_bands ORDER BY jm_dist) AS RN, 
               data_bands, 
               thematic_class1, 
               thematic_class2
               Avg(sep.jm_dist)OVER(partition BY data_bands) as avarage_jm_dist
               jm_dist  
        FROM   separabilities) A 
WHERE  rn = 1
```

or You need to join the result to main table to get the thematic_class1 and thematic_class2 for min `jm_dist` and `data_bands`

```
SELECT * 
FROM   separabilities A 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT sep.data_bands, 
                          Sum(sep.jm_dist) / Count(sep.data_bands) AS avarage_jm_dist
                          Min(jm_dist)                             AS jm_dist 
                   FROM   separabilities AS sep 
                   GROUP  BY sep.data_bands) B 
               ON A.data_bands = B.data_bands 
                  AND A.jm_dist = B.jm_dist 
ORDER  BY avarage_jm_dist
```

Comment: I use your first version and it works just fine. Thanks a lot!